# Parsing custom JSON into an ExtJS 4.1 TreeStore

Tags: extjs

I have an HTTP Server which responses with JSON strings. They look like this:

```
{
  ...
  "value":{
    "children":[
      {
        "path":"KEY_518693",
        "name":"KEY_518693",
        "children_count_overall":0,
        "children_page":1,
        "children_pages":1,
        "children_pagesize":10
        ...
      }
    ],
    "children_count_overall":1,
    "children_page":1,
    "children_pages":1,
    "children_pagesize":1,
    "name":null,
    "path":null,
    ...
  }
}
```

Every request has the parent node (in `"value"`), for which I requested the children and this children (in `"children"`), also some paging informations.

If no parent node was specified, it returns the root node as child of a virtual root node.

I set the `"root"` property of the proxy to `"value"`, so  the proxy knows where to search for the nodes, but the `tree` member of my TreeStore has a strange Structure after a `load()`:

```
tree: {
  childNodes: [
    {
      childNodes: [], <-- no child?
      data: {
        children: [
          { ...the raw data of the "children" node (like in the example above)...}
        ],
        ... the data of the "value" node and some data from the implicit node model...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Somehow the object in `"value"` gets converted to a node and inserted into the tree, but it's objects in the `"children"` array won't get converted and end up as data of this `"value"`node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeStore is meant to consume JSON Objects of the kind:

```
{
  "success": true, 
  "Root": [
          {...},{...},{...} //Children
          ]
}
```

As you're not specifying the array inside the Root node, all that information is passed as Raw data. Also, if you want to be able to access your data without having to go through the 'Raw' information it would be better to specify a Model in where you can specify which fields are inside each of the nodes data.

So basically I'd say it would be better to redo your Server response or go through that raw data yourself.